# Zoom on double-tap functionality using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile, zooming

I'm interested in adding a "zoom on double-tap" feature to images on my web page, so that mobile users will be able to zoom in and out by tapping on the images. Is it possible to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to say, most mobile OSs already have this functionality (iOS and Android have it for sure). No need for any jQuery scripting.

Comment: I want to build this app using the jquery mobile or with any jquery plugin for zoomin and zoomout

Comment: *Why*? This seems like reinventing the wheel, and just a needless complication. Perhaps if you edited your original question to include *as much relevant detail as possible*, you could get more relevant answers.